# Vue 3 & Typescript - How can I construct an array of a reusable component to pass into another component?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I have created a reusable Button but I want to be able to style it dynamically as well as pass in values for text/icons, etc.

The below is how I have constructed this "ActionButton"; I am relatively new to Vue 3 and have been trying to understand many of the aspects but I seem to be a little stumped on this issue.

```
<template>
    <button class="pr-5 mr-3" :class="buttonStyle">
        <span class="inline-block px-2">
            <svg class="inline-block"  :class="svgStyle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  :viewBox="svgViewBox" :fill="svgFill">
                <path :d="svgValue"/>
            </svg>
            <span class="inline-block ml-4" :class="textStyle">{{ inlineText }}</span>
        </span>
    </button>
</template>
  
  <script lang="ts" >
  import { defineComponent, computed } from "@vue/runtime-core";

  export default defineComponent({
    name: "ActionButton",
    props: {
        title: {
        required: false,
        type: String,
        default: "Title",
      },
      inlineText: {
        required: false,
        type: String,
        default: "Button",
      },
      inlineTextSize: {
        required: false,
        type: String,
        default: "text-xs"
      },
      inlineTextColor: {
        required: false,
        type: String,
        default: "text-white"
      },
      inlineFont: {
        required: false,
        type: String,
        default: "font-bold"
      },
      buttonCorners: {
        required: false,
        type: String,
        default: "rounded"
      },
      buttonHeight: {
        required: false,
        type: String,
        default: "h-6"
      },
      buttonWidth: {
        required: false,
        type: String,
        default: "w-auto"
      },
      buttonBgColor: {
        required: false,
        type: String,
        default: "bg-[#57cbc4]"
      },
      buttonHoverColor: {
        required:false,
        type: String,
        default: "hover:bg-blue-700"
      },
      svgValue: {
        required: false,
        type: String,
        default: "M13.05 42q-1.25 0-2.125-.875T10.05 39V10.5H8v-3h9.4V6h13.2v1.5H40v3h-2.05V39q0 1.2-.9 2.1-.9.9-2.1.9Zm21.9-31.5h-21.9V39h21.9Zm-16.6 24.2h3V14.75h-3Zm8.3 0h3V14.75h-3Zm-13.6-24.2V39Z"
      },
      svgHeight: {
        required: false,
        type: String,
        default: "h-5"
      },
      svgWidth: {
        required: false,
        type: String,
        default: "w-5"
      },
      svgFill: {
        required: false,
        type: String,
        default: "white"
      },
      svgViewBox: {
        required: false,
        type: String,
        default: "0 0 48 48"
      }
    },
    setup(props) {
        const buttonStyle = props.buttonCorners + " " + props.buttonHeight  + " " 
                + props.buttonWidth + " " + props.buttonBgColor + " " + props.buttonHoverColor;

        const svgStyle = props.svgHeight + " " + props.svgWidth;

        const textStyle = props.inlineTextSize + " " + props.inlineTextColor + " " + props.inlineFont;

        return {
            buttonStyle,
            svgStyle,
            textStyle
        }
    }
  });
  </script>
```

Any help on this would be great as I can see being able to reuse components like this very helpful over many pages that need to be designed for our project but would like to pass in as many buttons as needed as some of the components that will receive it are also reusable components so need to be dynamic component and per page.

I have been trying to construct this to pass in as an array of ActionButtons but I do not seem to understand how to construct it properly with the values needed.

This is what I have for now:

```
<image-card
         :client-projects="clientProjects"
         image-state="true"
         :action-buttons="cardActionButtons"
        />

const cardActionButtons = ref(
    [
       {
          title: "Edit Button",
          inlineText: "EDIT",
          inlineTextSize: "",
          inlineTextColor: "",
          inlineFont: "",
          buttonCorners: "",
          buttonHeight: "",
          buttonWidth: "",
          buttonBgColor: "",
          buttonHoverColor: "",
          svgValue: "M9 39h2.2l22.15-22.15-2.2-2.2L9 36.8Zm30.7-24.3-6.4-6.4 2.1-2.1q.85-.85 2.1-.85t2.1.85l2.2 2.2q.85.85.85 2.1t-.85 2.1Zm-2.1 2.1L12.4 42H6v-6.4l25.2-25.2Zm-5.35-1.05-1.1-1.1 2.2 2.2Z",
          svgHeight: "",
          svgWidth: "",
          svgFill: "",
          svgViewBox: ""
      },
    ]
  )
```

Comment: What you have now would be the "grandparent" component of the ActionButtons. `<image-card>` is the parent. What we don't know is how are you trying to display the ActionButtons inside `<image-card>`.  You should be importing the ActionButton component, rendering the number of ActionButtons you need in the template, and passing in props from the objects stored in the `action-buttons` array

Comment: The issue is that the card component is reusable across the app as well and may contain 1 to many action buttons depending on the page.

Comment: you can dynamically render a number of action buttons in `<image-card>` based on the length of `cardActionButtons` array using [v-for](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html).  All you would need to do on different pages is construct the array so that it contains however many buttons you want displayed within that page's `<image-card>`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `slots` in the `image-card` component and a `v-for` loop to iterate over your buttons array and provide the props.

Basically slot allows you to pass in dynamic content from the parent to child. So in your case in the grand parent component you can have the array of buttons and pass it to image-card with slots like so

**Parent [image-card.vue] Component**

```
<template>
//your code for image card component
<slot name=“button-slot”>
</template>
```

**Grand parent component where you are using image-card**

```
..
<image-card
         :client-projects="clientProjects"
         image-state="true"
        >
 <template #button-slot>
     <div v-for=“(button,index) in    cardActionButtons” :key=“index”>
       <ActionButton :button-width=“button.buttonWidth”>
//add other props
       </ActionButton>
   </div>
 </template>
</image-card>
..
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help! I did eventually figure it out using an interface and a class and then passing in an instance to the button(s)!